# Firebase rule validation for multiple path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there a smart declarative way to express the validation in `test` for "collection1" and "collection2", even if the number of collections increases? So that I don't have to repeat for each collection the same lines, similar to a loop.

```
match /orders/{orderId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null && test();
}
function test() {
  let docId = request.resource.id;
  let doc = /databases/$(database)/documents/collection1/$(docId);
  let isValid = exists(doc);
  doc = /databases/$(database)/documents/collection2/$(docId);
  return isValid || exists(doc);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no loops in security rules, and no way to iterate or count anything. This limitation is to prevent rules from spinning up too much work. Rules need to be fast since they apply to every matching access.

Also, [you can't read more than 10 documents in a single rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits) anyway, so writing them all out individually is not actually all that bad.

Comment: Can I use wildcard or regex pattern to apply `/databases/$(database)/documents/**/$(docId);` for all collections or certain collections which supply the pattern?

Comment: No. If you want to check if a document exists or read it, you need to provide an exact path for it.